# Texmaker: Is it possible to save all files on compile?

Tags: texmaker, external-files

When I press <kbd>F1</kbd> in Texmaker, is it possible to automatically save all files which belong to the "master" file?

If it is relevant: I am using Texmaker 4.1.

Comment: My TeXstudio automatically saves _all_ open files when I press `F1`, so something must be wrong with your editor …

Comment: Sorry! Misread that you’re talking about TeXmaker. But you may consider switching to TeXstudio ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this is accessible from the application itself, but you can set the option in the settings file: `texmaker.ini`. On Mac OSX and on Linux it is located in `~/.config/xm1/`

Inside that file, find the line:

`Editor\AutoSave=false`

and change it to

`Editor\AutoSave=true`

You may need to restart `texmaker` for the change to take place.

Comment: I'm looking for the texmaker.ini files but I don't find it inside the path: `~/.config/xm1/`. I'm using a MAC 10.11 SO. Any idea?