# Texmaker: automatically save .tex files currently opened every 5 minutes

Tags: texmaker

With Texmaker, is it possible to automatically save .tex files currently opened every 5 minutes?

I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147035/texmaker-is-it-possible-to-save-all-files-on-compile) related post, but the question is about saving automatically whenever compilation occurs. I sometimes write for a long time without compiling, so I don't find that safe enough. I would like the .tex file to save automatically every 5 minutes, regardless of how long ago it was last compiled.

---

I am using Texmaker 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

Comment: What is your precise question? Do you want to shorten the auto-save time intervall?

Comment: just edited, hope it's clearer now

Comment: In *Preferences > Editor*, there is a checkbox that reads "Backup document every 10 min"; it doesn't allow you to set a custom time. That's a dangerous feature, though: what if you experiment by removing a large part of the code and texmaker saves your file automatically? Better to save when you actually want to capture the state of your document, or, even better, use some version-control tool.

Comment: @Jubobs It is dangerous only if you don't **also** use version control. But version control alone isn't enough if, for example, your editor sometimes crashes or freezes or if your entire machine has a habit of simply switching itself off for no reason. (For historical reasons, my autosave is set to 1min intervals for just this reason. I'm not going to commit to the repo every 1min else I'd never actually write anything!) But a good editor will autosave while maintaining the ability to undo changes so you have a further safety net. (`svn revert` is for when all of that fails!)

Comment: @cfr If you commit often, you shouldn't be afraid to lose the changes since your last commit. In case you don't use any VCS, the autosave feature is really dangerous. Imagine the following situation: it saves at a time when you're not happy with the state of your document, and then you inadvertently close the app. Boom! The undo list is cleared, and you can't reopen your file to revert the changes. Screwed! At least, without autosave, trying to quit the app while some files are unsaved will prompt you for confirmation, giving you a change *not* to quit and record your file in a bad state.

Comment: @Jubobs I don't commit *that* often. That is, I think simple saving is a good compromise when I don't want to lose work but don't want to stop to commit. Autosave was exceptionally useful when my machine kept switching itself off. (I am not talking about clean shutdowns so the fact that my work was unsaved would not trigger a warning. Anything unsaved was lost.) Obviously that's not a standard situation and I could live without autosave now. I just don't think autosaving is itself dangerous. It *can* act as a safety net *if* part of an overall strategy of damage limitation.

Comment: @cfr Suit yourself, but let me stay away from it `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for the warning. Luckily I have a crontab set up that git commits every 10 minutes. so I guess autosave every 10 minutes is safe!

Comment: @AlexandreHoldenDaly Should I post my first comment as an answer to your question? By the way, using Cron for Git sounds totally crazy to me. In my opinion, each commit should be done in a conscious manner and have at least *some* meaning, instead of being created when 10 minutes happen to have elapsed since the last one. But we're veering off-topic...

Comment: @Jubobs feel free to post what you like as an answer, but personnally I value the different opinions voiced throughout these comments. Also on texmaker 4.1 I can't find Preferences > Editor anywhere... (finally, I'll start a post about committing on stackoverflow)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: It's Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Editor.

Comment: I'm a Mac user, so I don't know what Texmaker looks like on Linux. However, [this](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION0) suggests that you should follow, *Options*, *Configure Texmaker*, *Editor*.

Comment: @Jubobs Could you make your comments here into an answer?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

### Accessing Texmaker's autosave feature

Texmaker (at least 4.1 and newer) has an autosave feature. How you access it depends on your platform.

- On Linux (and Windows?), you need to follow *Options > Configure Texmaker > Editor*.
- On Mac OS X, you need to follow *Texmaker > Preferences > Editor*.

You should then see a checkbox that reads "Backup [sic] documents every 10 min".
As of Texmaker 4.2, the time interval between two autosaves is 10 minutes and cannot be adjusted by the user.

[image]

---

### Compiling often is good

In my opinion, you should compile relatively often. The benefits of compiling often are discussed in the answers to this [Programmers.SX question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245763/is-there-a-benefit-in-compiling-your-code-as-you-go-along), and apply to TeX & friends as well.

In a nutshell, you can think of compilation as a form of feedback. Compiling often means a short feedback loop: if you make a mistake, you'll find out about it more rapidly and you'll be able to correct it right away. By compiling comparatively less often, you expose yourself to the risk of getting into tricky situtations that you may have trouble extricating yourself from.

### Autosave is (mostly) evil

Autosave features such as that offered by Texmaker are dangerous. Imagine the following sequence of events.

1. Your document is a state that you're not happy with (perhaps you're making wild experiments with it, but you're not yet sure that you're happy with the results).
2. Texmaker's autosave feature saves  your document.
3. You inadvertently close Texmaker.

The last "good" version of your file is now irremediably gone! You could launch Texmaker again, reopen your file, but you wouldn't be able to undo any of the "bad" changes, because Texmaker's undo list was cleared when the app was closed.
This horror story, which isn't that farfetched, is scary enough to keep me away from using any form of autosave.

### Use a Version Control System (but not as an autosave!)

You should use some Version Control System instead of using Texmaker autosave feature. A VCS such as Git encourages you to take a snapshot of your project every time you feel that recording the current state might be useful. You can then move back and forth between versions, compare versions to see what changed, etc.

**However**, emulating some autosave feature with a VCS is wrong, IMO. For instance, [using `cron` to automatically commit every n minutes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186106/texmaker-automatically-save-tex-files-currently-opened-every-5-minutes?noredirect=1#comment430642_186106) is completely at odds with Git's philosophy. Each snapshot should instead be taken in a conscious manner and have some meaning attached to it, instead of being created in a rather arbitrary fashion, when n minutes happen to have elapsed since the last one.

Comment: Automatic backup is NOT autosave. Texmaker backup option creates a *.tex.bak file without erasing or modifying the original *.tex (so your dangerous exemple cannot happen here). It's a perfectly fine and safe feature to use (typically a lifesaver against losing all your edits if your computer crashes before you could save).

Answer (score 0):

Honest answer is Texmaker does not have auto save feature.

**Solution for me was to install [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/).**

TeXstudio builds on Texmaker and has many additional features including auto save enabled by default.