# error to open restored tex file after accidental delete

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I accidentally deleted a LaTeX file. I recuperated after using a restoration software, but when I try to open it, a pop up shows an encoding error stating the document can not be decoded correctly and proposed another encoding, which displays the document like in the capture [image]

Any solution please?

Comment: looks like a binary fragment of that file to me. What recovery software did you use? What were your steps of deleting the file? What are your system specs?

Comment: You seem to be using `TeXmaker`. Don't you have backup every 10 min?

Comment: thnaks for replay @naphaneal , I used EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard , I replaced the latex file with an older file ..,I am on windows 7

Comment: Did the pop-up tell you which encoding it used instead? Is there the possibility to choose another?

Comment: @samcarter yeah the popo-up propose another encoding but does not work

Comment: But before any experimentation: In case you still have a pdf file from the original save it to a different file name, so it won't be accidentally overwritten.

Comment: Yes, but did it say which encoding? And is there more than possibility to choose another encoding?

Comment: @Bernard I only have the old file

Comment: Based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186106/texmaker-automatically-save-tex-files-currently-opened-every-5-minutes, is there a file with the extension `.tex.bak`?

Comment: If it's 10 min old, it's OK. Not much is lost.

Comment: @samcarter the proposed encoding is ISO-8859-1 , or UTF -8

Comment: i didn't find a file with .tex.bak  extension ..

Comment: using the recovery software I found the pdf file corresponding to the recent latex file..

Comment: Well, that's something!

Comment: but I need the Latex source file

Comment: well, in the worst case you might have to reconstruct that from the PDF. if you can't find the related `.tex` this will be an available option. problem with data recovery is: the more you use your computer, the less likely it gets to get a good recovery of the lost file. the sectors on which the  file was stored are freed by the OS and overwritten in time by other files.

Comment: If the tex file is not confidential you could put it somewhere on the net. Then we could look if the content is lost or if you only have problem to open it. Beside this you are now learning why it is good to make backups ...